# Hide specific file with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried to hide two specific files on my webserver using this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond file1.php file2.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ file1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ file2.php [QSA,L]
```

I tried this but it didn't work.
I know the other way using mod-rewrite rule but that hides all file extensions which breaks other things as I run a forum on same server. I'm not even sure if it is possible to hide a specific files extension?

Comment: What do you mean by `hide`? What do you expect to happen if someone access the file you don't want? And what two exact files are you referring to?

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I am trying to hide the file extension from the URL by to hide two specific files extensions instead of all of them as it will break other scripts like my forum. Example,   www.example.com/file1.php to www.example.com/file1